# Cannot add Servlet in a Maven Project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm testing IntelliJ with a Maven Project, it creates the Project fine, the problem is that I don't see the option to add a Servlet, and i don't see an option to add a package eather. just JSP and JSF pages, this is the sub-menu I get, how can I add a servlet and a package?

[image: Anexed screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the folder on which you're invoking the context menu is not  marked as a "source" folder.

One way of marking it is to right-click on it (in your case the "java" folder) and choose "Mark Directory As > Sources Root".

Answer (score 2):

I was experimenting a bit and came across a scenario which may be helpful for someone.
I created a directory main\java, which was created as a maven source directories as suggested by Intellij by default as shown in image.[image: main\java]
Then i marked src as source directory and i do not get option to create new servlet under created java directory.
So in this particular case if you want to create servlet then first go to, "Mark directory as > Unmark as sources root".
Now you can create servlet inside java directory as well.

Comment: Also you can try out by updating maven project. Go to, "View> Tools Windows> Maven" then try,"Reimport All Maven Projects and Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects".

Answer (score 0):

in resources create a folder java in that folder create a package and in that package create a servlet

[image: structure]